# Java: Autogenerating documentation for Strategy Pattern with lambdas

Tags: java, design-patterns, documentation, java-ee

### Situation

Object `MyObject` needs to be sent to one of our downstream systems depending on the enum value of its field `myField`.

```
public class MyObject {
  private MyEnum myField;
  public MyEnum getMyField() {return myField;}
}
```

For this we are using the strategy pattern implemented with lambdas, like so:

```
public class ProcessingStrategies {

   private final EnumMap<MyEnum, Consumer<MyObject>> lookupStrategy = new EnumMap<>(MyEnum.class);

   public ProcessingStrategies() {
      lookupStrategy.put(MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE_1, this::sendToSystemA);
      lookupStrategy.put(MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE_2, this::sendToSystemB);
      lookupStrategy.put(MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE_3, this::sendToSystemC);
   }

   public void processMyObject(final MyObject myObject) {
      lookupStrategy.get(myObject.getMyField()).accept(myObject);
   }

   private void sendToSystemA(final MyObject myObject) {
      // logic here
   }

   private void sendToSystemB(final MyObject myObject) {
      // logic here
   }

   private void sendToSystemC(final MyObject myObject) {
      // logic here
   }
}
```

So far so good.

### Question

Now we would like to generate some human-readable documentation from this setup, to show which values of `MyEnum` go to which downstream systems. **What would be an elegant way to do this?** We considered several options, but none were really appealing:

- Using a configuration file instead of hard-coding. Pro: we don't need to document the code, we can document the config instead. Con: would require rewriting the class from scratch and pulling in a configuration framework, solely for documentation purposes
- Using classes instead of lamdas for the strategies. Pro: each class can get a "description" string which can be used for documentation. Con: this would quickly proliferate into a large number of tiny classes, due to the number of downstream systems and their respective interfaces
- Using (javadoc?) annotations on the different strategies. Pro: minimal change to existing code. Con: doesn't seem to actually work with lambdas in the middle (see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22435715/8771046) on StackOverflow).

We are also open to refactoring the code, should a better solution exist.

**Bonus points:** our department's preferred documentation framework compiles and runs a "documenter" executable on the build servers. The gold-plated solution would be to pass this application a `Map<MyEnum, String>` that for each value of `MyEnum` contains a human-readable description string.

Comment: Have you considered some sort of Markdown file to hold this documentation? It looks like you have done a good job evaluating the solutions that are available. Right now it seems this question is asking for tool recommendations, which is off-topic, but some of the options you considered involve different code designs, which might be on-topic.

Comment: Are you not able to capture this information in Javadoc comments on the enum itself?

Comment: @GregBurghardt We want to generate this documentation directly from the code, rather than in a separate file somewhere that needs to be maintained separately. A Javadoc comment on the enum would essentially amount to the second as well (besides the fact that this enum is used for more than just this one purpose).

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that your "logic here" is just some lightweight dispatching code. If so you can refactor your code to something like this:

```
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

public enum MyEnum {
    /**
     * Java doc for Value 1
     */
    ENUM_VALUE_1(MyEnum::sendToSystemA),
    /**
     * Java doc for Value 2
     */
    ENUM_VALUE_2(MyEnum::sendToSystemB);

    private final BiConsumer<MyObject, Context> consumer;

    MyEnum(final BiConsumer<MyObject, Context> consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    public void processMyObject(final MyObject myObject, final Context context) {
        consumer.accept(myObject, context);
    }

    private static void sendToSystemA(final MyObject myObject, final Context context) {
        // logic here
    }

    private static void sendToSystemB(final MyObject myObject, final Context context) {
        // logic here
    }
}
```

**Pros**

- You can now JavaDoc the enum value and the dispatch together - since they are both in the same file - actually on the same line.
- Some compile time checking, since each enum must have a lambda associated with it when it's defined.

NOTE: If you had a fixed number (2 or 3) patterns you could kludge this approach - I am not going to recommend that though.

**Cons**

- Doesn't support a large number of dispatch patterns.
- I had to make the lambdas static in order to include them in the constructor for the enum, this is why I changed from Consumer to BiConsumer, so I could include some context to immediately break out of the static context.

**Misc**

- The "sendToSystemX()" methods don't have to be located in the enum - you can relocate them somewhere else - but the "first" method would still need to be static in order to be able to include it in the enum constructor.

Comment: Thanks, this is going in the right direction. We would prefer to keep the enum standalone though, because it controls more than just the dispatching - tying it all into the enum would make a bad case of "God class".

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Javadoc spec](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html#format), you can include simple HTML formatting in descriptions. Rather than get fancy, keep it simple:

```java
public class ProcessingStrategies {

   /**
    * Good, solid introductory paragraph here.
    * <p>
    * Another paragraph.
    * <ul>
    * <li>Include bullet lists
    * <li>With multiple items if you want
    * </ul>
    */
   private final EnumMap<MyEnum, Consumer<MyObject>> lookupStrategy = new EnumMap<>(MyEnum.class);
```

While Javadoc ignores private members by default, including the Javadoc comments above the field should trigger the tool to generate this information. This gives you some simple formatting options to describe how this object is used in greater detail while keeping this documentation in the source.

More examples here: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html#examples